# Using NVME SSDs as memory while prioritizing real memory (limiting virtual memory to specific tasks)

Tags: hard-drive, memory, ssd, performance

we have one scenario where local storage is not enough and we need to utilize network storage. Since network storage comes with latency and is slow (HDDs in this case), is there a way to extend the memory with the Storage Capacity of NVME SSDs for system file caching (database) while preserving the real memory for low latency tasks?

Comment: Depending on the nature of your network storage and the rest of the setup, you could just use `bcache` or something similar.

Comment: Which operating system(s)?

Comment: @harrymc ubuntu

Comment: Bcache sounds very interesting, I'll dig into it.